# Do we need a generic off-topic close reason?

Tags: discussion, voting, close-reasons

I don't have vote to close privileges here, but wanted to [flag this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96882/which-website-provide-ios-games-download-statistics) as off topic. Simply because it's not in the scope of this site, and just asking for an external website.

However, the three *off topic* options I have are:

> - Questions about software development are off-topic here, but can be asked on Stack Overflow.
> - Questions about pre-release software are off-topic. For more information, see Can we ask about iOS 7 and OS X Mavericks? and Can I ask about not-yet-publicly released OS?.
> - This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Neither of these applies, and unfortunately I can't add any custom close reason as well. The only option I have now is to use a custom moderator flag, but as of late, closure flags are not shown to moderators and go straight to the review queue—but when using a custom flag I'd overrule this and cause additional workload for mods, while the community could handle this itself.

Would a more generic off-topic close reason make sense?

Comment: see http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/how-to-flag-this-type-of-question for a possible answer

Comment: I guess it boils down to whether moderators want to see custom flags being "abused" for what should be a close vote.

Comment: "Flagging for attention" is ok for me, it's primarily saying "Hey moderator, have a look at that question".

Comment: Our flag volume makes using other a fair workaround, but it's not a "clean solution" as you point out. Tis must be a systematic issue since why make easpch site have a generic close reason. I'll look on the main meta for a relevant thread in a bit....

Comment: Since the link is now dead it is quite ironic that the discussion on this question will never get an answer. The description given is just too vague and: "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed." should also apply to questions. Especially when internal links might disappear. Like the one above.